# Class Members -- Java vs. Python

Tags: java, python

I am coming from Java and learning Python, now. I try to understand the concept of class members in Python.

Here is an example program in Java:

```
class Hello {
    int x = 0;

    void ex() {
        x = 7;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Hello h = new Hello();
        System.out.println(h.x);
        h.ex();
        System.out.println(h.x);
}   }
```

That is what I did in Python, following some examples I found:

```
class Hello:
   def __init__(self) :
       self.x = 0

   def ex(self):
       self.x = 7

h = Hello()
print(h.x)
h.ex()
print(h.x)
```

Both programs return:

```
0
7
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is the Python Code correct?
2. The programming style of Python appears to me to be more compact, compared to Java. So I am wondering, **WHY** does Python require the passing of a "self" -- Parameter.
3. At this point Python seems to be more "complex" than Java. Or is there a way to remove the "self" -- Parameter?

Comment: (1) Yes. (2) Google your question exactly like that. (3) Maybe, but if there is, it's obscure and you shouldn't do it.

Comment: AFAIK the Python code is correct. And I think the "self" is more needed because of Python's philosophy rather than technical necessity. Eyeing towards Python's lack of braces for delimiting code blocks and instead strictly sticking to indentation, which is, like I think I read sometime ago, because of the philosophy that the programs get more readable with proper indentation. In this case here: requiring you to explicitly state that you mean the instance variable and not a local variable to keep things unambiguous. (I even use explicit "this" in Java for that reason...)

Comment: `self` is exposed in Python because "Explicit is better than implicit" (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).  I would rather ask "why does Java have a magic undeclared variable called 'this'"?  (probably because C++ has).

Comment: As a tip, try to avoid accesing instance members directly in Java, even if it is just for reading. In general, favor reducing member access to the least amount necessary (usually `private` is best, unless you need inheritance, in which case you shoud use `protected`). Use accessor methods instead, which guarantee that each class controls its own members under all circumstances and reduces coupling of consumers their implementation. I realize this is just an example, so by all means ignore my comment if you already know this. It might be useful for someone newer, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, your python code is correct.

It's just a matter about how the languages is designed. Java uses a kind of automatic inference of a reference to the object. It can lead sometimes to strange behaviours for non-java experts:

```
private int a; 
public int add(int a, int b){
    return a+b; // what a will it use? 
}
```

So, it's why in java there's the keyword `this` that can be used (but you're not forced) in order to solve that ambiguity.

The python team decided to force to use the word self (or any other word but I will explain later) to avoid that kind of problem. You cannot get rid of it. Though, java is still a more verbose language than python and the keyword self doesn't affect a lot that assumption.

However you're not obliged to use the "self" word as a reference to the current object. You can use any other word that would be the first parameter of your method (but it's a very bad practice).

Here, you can see two references that explain deeply why "self is here to stay":

http://www.programiz.com/article/python-self-why

http://neopythonic.blogspot.be/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html

Comment: `self` is to my knowledge only a convention. You could use `this` instead: http://ideone.com/B5Kn0j

Comment: @zapl he addressed this in the last paragraph

Comment: @zapl you could call it `banana`, but don't; naming conventions reduce wasted time.

Comment: I added a small text to indicate that you can choose any word :)

Comment: shouldn't the "a" that is used be the single most granular reference, which in our case would be the parameter "a" and not the attribute "a"?

Comment: Yes, in java it would be the parameter but new programmers can make a mistake :)

Comment: `self` is specified in PEP008: "*Always use self for the first argument to instance methods.*"

Comment: Ok ,I added a warning message (it's a very bad practice ;) )

Comment: It is not the "self". I was wondering whether I can leave it just like "this" in Java.

Comment: @scarecrow- correct; however, there is a considerable loss in readability (and one might argue added ambiguity) because of that. Basically, modifying the execution of the code, implicitly, based on scope, is not as clear. In Java, I would still prefer using `this.a` to avoid misinterpretations. In Python, the language enforces that pattern, which to me is superior.

Answer (score 0):

So in java the structure is generally

```
Class
      private data (aka the "struct")
      public data
      constructors (__init__ in python)
      functions etc
```

its very similar in python. same structure just for any functions working with the data you need to put self as an argument. where java it didn't have to take arguments.

Also it seems in python all data is public by default so you don't need to use getters and setters like in java.

personally I find a Python class more of a C-Struct with some added features, where java everything is thrown into a class.

Answer (score 0):

For what's worth you can save a few line of codes when you have many fields, by using a library to remove the boilerplate. For example with [`pyfields`](https://smarie.github.io/python-pyfields/):

```
from pyfields import field, make_init

class Hello:
    x = field(default=0)
    y = field()
    __init__ = make_init()

h = Hello(y=10)
print((h.x, h.y))
```

yields

```
(0, 10)
```

You can even combine it with `autoclass` to get several features out of the box:

```
from autoclass import autoclass
from pyfields import field

@autoclass
class Hello:
    x = field(default=0)
    y = field()

h = Hello(y=1)
print(h)
assert h == {'x': 0, 'y': 1}
print(dict(h))
```

yields

```
Hello(x=0, y=1)
{'x': 0, 'y': 1}
```

See [documentation](https://smarie.github.io/python-pyfields/) for details. I'm the author by the way ;)

Answer (score -2):

2.)Python is a high level language. where java is more mid-high im guessing. kind of new to java.

python goes by white space, where java requires more formatting.

3.) the self parameter can be removed. replace with whatever you want to call it.

Comment: *"im guessing"* - please don't.